# Find dates based on conditions and shift before and after

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am currently analysing some time-series data in python and I need to find the begin and end of an event based on other columns values.

My dataframe looks roughly like this:

```
         Month      Price  Change
9  2009-06-01  144384.10  0.1112
10 2009-07-01  132549.80  -0.082
11 2009-08-01  144611.00   0.091
12 2009-09-01  135389.50 -0.0638
13 2009-10-01  140593.30  0.0384
14 2009-11-01  153151.70  0.0893
15 2009-12-01  151010.80  -0.014
16 2010-01-01  152519.30    0.01
17 2010-02-01  145998.30 -0.0428
18 2010-03-01  151475.30  0.0375
19 2010-04-01  163071.70  0.0766
20 2010-05-01  150044.20 -0.0799
21 2010-06-01  143950.30 -0.0406
22 2010-07-01  139866.00 -0.0284
23 2010-08-01  137859.00 -0.0143
```

Lets say I have a crisis mid 2010. I want to find the first date of the crisis by looking at the `Change` column. 
I have the following code, but I wonder if it can be written a bit more efficient, since this is only the part for the begin of the crisis:

```
crisis = df
crisis["month_1"] = crisis["Month"].shift(1)
crisis = crisis[(crisis["Change"]< 0) & (crisis["Month"] > "2010-02-01")]
start_date = crisis["month_1"].iloc[0]
```

Comment: Please explain your intended output and how it differs from what you have now?

Comment: The code works, but I would love to write it in 1-2- lines. start_date = "2010-04-01"